# Mapping species occurrences in R

Tags: r, mapping

I'm quite beginner at R so I'm struggling with what I've found on google for how to plot species occurrence data points in R (I know how in QGIS but my supervisors want R) and then fill in 10km or 1km grid squares where the species has occurred. The photo shows what I mean but has been produced in DMap [rosemarybeetlemap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3h44.png)

The main issue I have is that my csv file of records only has alphanumeric Ordnance Survey grid references - can R plot with these or do they need to be split into easting/northings or even decimal latitude/longitude? and if so, how?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hey, I see that you're pretty new here and you've asked similar questions without fruitful responses. It's quite likely that people are lacking the information they need to help you, I'd recommend reading this webpage: https://www.tidyverse.org/help/  and creating a reprex, seems likely you'll get the answers to your question if you can do that :)

Comment: Have you seen this? https://rspatial.org/raster/cases/3-speciesdistribution.html

Answer (score 0):

Locations detailed in Ordnance Survey’s National Grid (NGR) format in contrast to using eastings and northings (in metres) splits the Great Britain into lettered grid squares and then defines locations within each lettered grid square. You know but some explanation you'll find here as a [beginners guide to finding grid references](https://getoutside.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/guides/beginners-guide-to-grid-references/)).

For your main issue following article maybe a solution for a first step [Converting (British) National Grid references](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/10/converting-british-national-grid-references/#google_vignette).

I quoted some info below (credits to mikerspencer and Claudia Vitolo).

> There’s no need to write a script from scratch to convert grid references, [someone has done it already](https://github.com/cvitolo/rnrfa)! There is some legwork to do in getting your NGR coordinates in a format ready for the conversion. The script that follows does just that, taking a csv file as your start and end point.